# import error: cannot import name 'HTTPError' from urllib3.exceptions

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I had a .py file that used to work for web scraping gas prices from gasbuddy using selenium and phantomjs. It used to work, but it stopped all of a sudden. So I uninstalled and reinstalled selenium and phantomJS. I uninstalled and reinstalled Python 3 using homebrew. I even erased my MacBook and reinstalled Sierra on it, and reinstalled everything else What doesn't make sense to me is that I'm getting importing errors for modules I'm not even importing.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_log_path=os.path.devnull)

driver.get('https://www.gasbuddy.com/station/155967')
price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/h1')
print(price.text)
```

and the errors that I get are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/igisan/Desktop/scripts/gas.py", line 2, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 29, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver as RemoteWebDriver
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .remote_connection import RemoteConnection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 24, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .exceptions import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/exceptions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 203, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email._policybase import compat32
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/email/_policybase.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email.utils import _has_surrogates
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/email/utils.py", line 33, in <module>
    from email._parseaddr import quote
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/email/_parseaddr.py", line 16, in <module>
    import time, calendar
  File "/Users/igisan/Desktop/scripts/calendar.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pyicloud import PyiCloudService
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyicloud/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pyicloud.base import PyiCloudService
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyicloud/base.py", line 7, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    from .exceptions import RequestsDependencyWarning
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/exceptions.py", line 9, in <module>
    from urllib3.exceptions import HTTPError as BaseHTTPError
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPError' from 'urllib3.exceptions' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/exceptions.py)
```

I even updated everything. Installing and reinstalling urllib didn't make a difference. I've also tried using other webscraping methods (lxml, etc.) but to no avail. Any answers?

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**
You have a circular import of `urllib3.exceptions`. `/Users/igisan/Desktop/scripts/calendar.py` shadows the `calendar` module of the Python standard lib. Rename that module.

Your Python env appears to be quite a bit messy. Importing `webdriver` looks normal up to the point where the underlying import of `urllib3.exceptions` resolves `http.client` not to the site-packages of that local Python 3.7 interpreter but to that of what appears to be a homebrew installation of Python 3.7.2 under `/usr/local/Cellar`.

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
```

From there you have a normal chain of imports within that homebrew module until `email._parseaddr` tries to import `calendar`. 
This import should go to the `calendar.py` module in the Python standard lib, but since you have a `calendar.py` in your `/Users/igisan/Desktop/scripts` folder, which apparently is added to `sys.path` (presumably through `PYTHONPATH`) the interpreter resolves to *your* `calendar.py`.

```
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/email/_parseaddr.py", line 16, in <module>
    import time, calendar
  File "/Users/igisan/Desktop/scripts/calendar.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pyicloud import PyiCloudService
```

*Your* `calendar.py` imports some class from the `pyicloud` package, which results in an attempt to import `requests`, which results in an attempt to import `urllib3.exceptions`. 
This becomes a circular import at that point. Importing `urllib3.exceptions` leads to the import of a module that tries to import `urllib3.exceptions`.
This issue should be resolved by renaming `/Users/igisan/Desktop/scripts/calendar.py` to something that does not shadow the module `calendar` from the standard lib.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem after I renamed my main module to `email.py`. It started conflicting with libraries `requests` and `selenium`. After renaming from `email.py` to something more original the error was gone.